# Copying Email message to another folder in Outlook Web Add-in

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office-js, outlook-web-addins, office365api

I've looked at the "outlook add in command demo" example that shows how to access properties of email messages and change them via REST.
However, I cannot seem to find how I would go about copying a message from (e.g. the Inbox) to another folder in the mailbox.
The example uses REST, which does not seem to be exposing a method or call to copy a message to another folder. Would I need to use Graph to copy a message, and if yes, how is this done from within an Outlook Add-in?
Also, the documentation says REST is deprecated for Outlook add-ins and Graph should be used instead. Is there an Outlook Add-in sample that uses Graph?
The example also shows how the add-in can work on iOS, but not on Android. Has this support in the meantime been added? Is there any newer example that shows how an Outlook add-in can work on all platforms including Android?

Comment: You should now use Graph in place of Outlook REST which is now deprecated. To call Graph via outlook add in, check the documentaion:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/authentication. Graph call to copy a message from 1 folder to another is POST /me/messages/{id}/move, find more info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/#outlook-rest-api-via-microsoft-graph
The Outlook Add in does have support for Android, please have a  look : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-mobile-addins

Comment: Thanks @FionaMatu for the comment. This is useful, please make it the answer.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, sure!

Answer (score 0):

You should now use Graph in place of Outlook REST which is now deprecated. To call Graph via outlook add in, check [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/authentication). Graph call to copy a message from 1 folder to another is POST /me/messages/{id}/move, find more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/#outlook-rest-api-via-microsoft-graph).
The Outlook Add in does have support for Android, please have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-mobile-addins)